# VBA Regex: Match not showing any value

Tags: regex, vba, excel

The following code is what ive come up with so far. I have also set the reference for regular expression 5.5.

However the match value does not show at all, am I missing something here??

```
Public Sub check()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'Prepare a regular expression object
Dim myRegExp As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As match
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^\d{6,8}-[SFTG]\d{7}[A-Z]-([^-]+)$"
Set myRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

cellValue = CStr(wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value) 
'123456-S1234567F-Scholarship Form 

If myRegExp.Test(cellValue) Then


Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(cellValue)


For Each myMatch In myMatches
  MsgBox (myMatch.Value)

Next

Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please provide values in `wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value` which you want to parse.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, i forgot to include:

123456-S1234567F-Scholarship Form

Comment: What do you want from `123456-S1234567F-Scholarship Form` string ?

Comment: To see whether it matches the regex pattern

Comment: Simply play [here](http://regexr.com?36fvp)

Comment: Yes, but i need it to work in excel macro before i carry on with other macro functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following line

```
Set myRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
```

seems to solve the issue.

I guess that's because all your initialization statements are gone when you assign `myRegExp` to a new object